# How does Open Source Drools and RedHatBRMS differ. Is it not a good idea to use Open Source Drools in Production environment

Tags: open-source, drools, redhat, enterprise, redhat-brms

Based on my understanding, all the components in RedHat BRMS can be achieved by integrating various drools components. So, is it a bad idea to use drools in Production?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. The difference is that if you pay RedHat you will have support from them if you need advice or you find any problem.
If you use the Open Source version, you will have all of the features present in the payed version (or even more), but you are basically on your own.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

Along with support you will get patches on regular basis for reported issues. You wont get any patch for community release of Drools/jBPM.